# font-face alternatives

Tags: css, cross-browser, font-face

My client (who is obsessed with pixel perfection) dislikes the way browsers render font-face fonts.

At the moment I am using font-squirrel to convert OTF fonts to webfonts.

The problem is, I don't see any alternatives. I could create a PNG file holding all these texts, but that doesn't sound like a browser-user-friendly solution.

The typical example of a design I have to work on is:

[image: hunger games screen grab]

What would be your approach?

> I'm assuming that by "dislikes the way browsers render @font-face" your'e referring to the blink which happens. If not, you should elaborate.

[image: difference]

The top one is web-font and the bottom one is screengrab from PSD. Both using same font family, same spacing. The client wants to look it more like the bottom one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that by "dislikes the way browsers render @font-face" your'e referring to the blink which happens. If not, you should elaborate.

Currently there's only 3 options to remove that blink. The first two are obvious solutions - use images, or use web safe fonts. These, obviously, defeat the purpose.

The third option is to embed base64 code for the fonts in your CSS. This increases the size (kb) of your CSS files, but it will completely eliminate the blink which tends to occur because the font is loaded with the CSS so there's no blink when a secondary file is loaded.

usage for including bas64 fonts looks like this:

```
 @font-face {
 font-family: "FontName";
 src: url("data:font/opentype;base64,[   the base64 code here   ]");
 }
```

There are a few online bas64 converters that you can feed a .otf file to and they'll spit out the base64 code. [Here's one such converter.](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp)

Comment: Either that, or the crappy anti-aliasing Windows is known for :)

Comment: Fun fact: this phenomenon is usually called the "flash of unstyled text", or "FOUT". In Dutch, "fout" means "wrong". :-P

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can not control browser anti-aliasing.

Comment: Anyway, this didn't have any effect on my issue. By now, I am pretty sure it is browser rendering to blame, rather than font-squirrel doing a bad job in handling OpenType fonts.

Comment: I didn't know that you can embed fonts as base64 code, do you have a url list all possible files that could embedded as base46?

Answer (score 0):

Another common and popular way of handling this is **automatic font replacement** (using JavaScript). This solution is friendly to users of screen readers, because the HTML contains plain text and the replacement is done using JavaScript, in the browser.

An example of this is technique is [sIFR](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr/), which is open source and uses Flash as the replacement.

Comment: Note that this won't work everywhere though. Won't work in iOS in particular, since Flash players cannot be installed there.

Comment: By the way: there are alternatives that don't rely on Flash, such as FLIR, but they're generally a pain to set up.

Answer (score 0):

An approach that I have used is to create background images to represent all display-text, and then use CSS to "hide" the actual text, and show only the image. For the sake of accessibility, the text should not be hidden using display:none or display:hidden though. Instead, use a large negative text indent to move the text off the left side of the display, or put it in a nested, absolutely-positioned element somewhere outside of the display area.

I usually use the negative indentation for all text not contained in a clickable element, and the nested, absolutely positioned element technique for anything that is contained in a clickable element (so the active element outline does not expand off the left side as can happen in some browsers).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has been bolded. Try setting `font-weight` to normal.

Comment: No, the font-weight is set to normal.

Comment: well that's weird. have you tride to override it with !important?

Comment: I can see it from the firebug that it is font-weight normal.